Spring Data JPA - Many To Many - Set returns empty collection
When I try to get user object from database empty collection is returned only if collection of observed is type of Set.
User class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {
    ...

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Offer> offers;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id")
    )
    private Set<Offer> observed;

    ...
}

Offer class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "offers")
@Data
public class Offer {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "observed")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<User> observers;
 
    ...
}

When I change collection observed from Set to List everything works fine.
User class:
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User implements UserDetails {
    ...

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Offer> offers;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "offer_id")
    )
    private List<Offer> observed;

    ...
}


I found out solution. You need to generate hashcode and equals by yourself, not by Lombok.
https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/
